# Malformed query in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

```
    search = {
      "from": str(start),
      "size": str(size),
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "multi_match": {
              "query":query,
              "fields":["name","description","tags","comments","created","creator","transaction","wallet"],
              "operator":"or"}
          },
          "filter": { "term": { "channel": channel } } } } }
```

This is the python dict object.  It gets the following error:

```
elasticsearch.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', '[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]')
```

I'm not seeing it.  Please help.  Start, size, query, and channel are all variables.

I have looked at a lot of example elasticsearch queries.  Nothing I've tried has gotten passed syntax errors.  I've also tried simple_search_string and a simple multi_match.  I always need start and size, and always need to filter on channel.

Comment: are you sure that query and channel is not null while making the query. Also, Can you please post python code snippet where you are passing this query. Elasticsearch query looks good for me.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is some of those fields are arrays and need [] inside them.  Specifically must and filter.  Adding appropriate braces solved the issue.  Here's the new format:

```
search = {
  "from": start,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "multi_match": {
          "query": query,
          "fields": ["name","description","tags","comments","created","creator","transaction","wallet"]
        } },
        { "match": {
          "channel": channel
        } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Notice I've also dropped using the filter and just added another match term.  I'm using size in the search call as one of its parameters.